# How to specify a pip version in pipenv

Tags: pip, pipenv

When I do `pipenv install pip=20.3.4` the right `pip` version is installed. But upon locking, the `pip` version is not present in `pipfile.lock`.

Creating a new `pipenv` from the locked file does not use the required `pip` version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround we did was to install the right pip version after the pipenv environment is created:

```
echo "Forcing pipenv to install the pip version set in pipfile..."
pip_version=$$(awk -F'"' '/^pip ?=/{print $$(NF-1)}' Pipfile); \
pipenv run pip install "pip$${pip_version}" --reinstall
```

Comment: So it has to be manually run after `pipenv install`? I would think you needed a `--reinstall` just to ensure in case pipfile has lower version that what was originally installed.